# Use Maclaurin series to calculate e^(0.1)

Tags: calculus

[image]

Tricky Question I think! Not quite sure what I am suppose to do a after I find the derivatives.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you come to the conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the mauclaurin series with remainder using Langrange Form.
Assume initial bound of $e^c< 3$  for some $c$ in $(0, 0.1)$
Find $n$ such that Rn $< 10^{-5}$

For $\sin x$, $\cos x$ proceed in the same way. Assume initial bound $1$ for these cases.

Comment: You know the series for Exp[x] around 0. Replace x by 0.1. The fifth term is then 10^(-4)/24 [this is 4.17 10^(-6)]. You do not need to compute all previous terms. Just use first visual inspection to decide on how many terms to add. When done, compute the sum up to the decided place.